# DefWindowProc call not working on Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, windows-8

I am having a problem calling DefWindowsProc on Windows 8 from a C# winform. I have this form that I need it to be dragabble from anywhwere inside the form.

Here is my code.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ReleaseCapture(IntPtr hwnd);

const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
const uint MOUSE_MOVE = 0xF012;

public void Drag()
{
    DefWindowProc(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (UIntPtr)MOUSE_MOVE, IntPtr.Zero);
}


private void OnMainPanelMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = sender as Control;
    ReleaseCapture(ctrl.Handle);

    this.Drag(); // put the form into drag mode.
}
```

DefWindowProc always return 0 yet I am unable to drag my window. This call works on XP, Vista and 7 but not on 8. I am guessing it has something to do with the decleration of DefWindowProc that is not working well on Windows 8.

Please note that on Windows 8 I am building my application with the .NET 4.0 framework yet on other platforms I am using the 2.0 version to build the software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved your functionality with a slightly different approach.

I'm running Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012.

I tested my solution an all versions of the framework, versions 2, 3, 4, 4.5.

Of course your main form will need to trap the mouse_down() method.

```
  private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(282, 253);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.mouse_down);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

First I defined a class called UnsafeNativeMethods:

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
{
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "ReleaseCapture")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

}
```

Inside the form you wish to move with mouse from anywhere:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void mouse_down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            UnsafeNativeMethods.ReleaseCapture();
            UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(Handle, UnsafeNativeMethods.WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, UnsafeNativeMethods.HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all, the window still can't be moved beyond the top edge of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I re-wrote the example to see if the behavior was different with DefWindowProc(). It wasn't. The form will still dock to the edge when dragged beyond.

Nevertheless, here is the  code:

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods2
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, ref int lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int ReleaseCapture(IntPtr hwnd);

    public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
    public const int MOUSE_MOVE = 0xF012;
}
```

Here is the code inside the form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void mouse_down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Control ctrl = sender as Control;
        UnsafeNativeMethods2.ReleaseCapture(ctrl.Handle);
        this.Drag(); // put the form into drag mode.

    }
    public void Drag()
    {
        UnsafeNativeMethods2.DefWindowProc(this.Handle, UnsafeNativeMethods2.WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr) UnsafeNativeMethods2.MOUSE_MOVE, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

My DefWindowProc() is declared slightly differently from yours.

Bottom line, both approaches achieve the same result - the ability to drag a window from anywhere in a form.